# Un-hide div when window is scrolled down using jQuery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, scroll

I'm trying to display a small 'back to top' div when I scroll down on my site.
Here is the code for my div (the style is inline whilst in development until I go through and move it all to a base.css file later on).

```
    <div id="backToTop" style="position:fixed; right:10px; top: 200px; width: 50px; height:50px; color:#ffffff; background-color:#000000; visibility:hidden"><a href="#top">Back to Top</a></div>
```

Fairly straightforward as you can see. I'm then trying to use jQuery to detect when the window has been scrolled down slightly to then show the div:

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       if($document).scrollTop() > 0){
          $('#backToTop').show();
       }else{
          $('#backToTop').hide();
       }
    });
```

My problem is that the script doesn't appear to be triggered. When I scroll down the page, the div does not appear.

I have additional jQUery on my page for form validation so I have tried including this alongside that function within:

```
    $().ready(function(){ /* Code goes here */ }
```

I've also tried including it outside of this but I've had no joy. I'm using Twitter bootstrap for the remainder of my page.

If anyone could point me in the direction of why this perfectly valid code isn't working, that would be great.

Cheers,

J

Comment: Yes, `if($document).` has to be `if($(document).` and it works

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is was due to small typo error

Comment: No. It's not due to a typo. That type was present but the problem till persists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

```
if($document).scrollTop() > 0){
```

There's a missing `(`:

```
if( $(document).scrollTop() > 0 ) {
     ^
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/U7scm/

**Edit**

I also noticed that you're setting `visibility: hidden`. jQuery's `.show()` and `.hide()` functions will toggle the `display` property, so use `display: none` instead of `visibility: hidden`

Comment: Tried that. Still no joy :-(

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works unless there are other things going on in your code that you haven't shared. Check the link I included in my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer with an additional find. Yes, your code should be wrapped by `$.ready`

Comment: Thanks Andre. Should have noticed the typo but then again I'm programming this site in my lunch hour so I'm in a bit of a rush. The visibility property was where I was going wrong.